# Shell script to grep multiple occurrence of a word in logs

Tags: linux, shell-script

my requirement is as below:

i have a application server logs from which i need to grep for certain word say "hung" and restart the server if i found the word. i have written the script but there was a strange issue which is at first occurrence it finds and restarts the server but again after next interval of corn job it runs again and finds same word and keeps on restarting the server on every interval. how do i avoid this situation.

i want shell not to pick previously read message. can anyone help me on this

Comment: Yes, the word doesn't disappear from the log just because you restart the machine...

Comment: You should look into using something like inotify integrated with tail -f for this. You can then action a script checking for certain data when the log is appended.

Comment: @Kusalananda yeah thats what the issue is. any solution here?

Comment: Do the logs have a timestamp on each line?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick yeah they do have time stamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your script move the file to a different name just before restart. This way, you have a fresh, empty file at restart.

Say you're rebooting after finding the work in /var/log/app.log

```
Scritp ...

...
...

mv /var/log/app.log /var/log/app.lo.back
reboot
```

Comment: Alex, thanks for the suggestion and i believe this is the solution. infact i am trying to implement same solution and finding if my app server can do it for me. i.e., rotate the log when it restarts.